# Osmdroid 4.3 - double taps on overlays

Tags: android, osmdroid

I have imported Osmdroid 4.3 into my application, but I have problem while tapping on displayed overlays. After I have moved over the map, I have to double tap overlay to display what I want, then, when I tap anotehr overlay, it just needs single tap (= the right way, app is programmed).

Question is, anyone faced same problem with newest osmdroid while taping on the objects on the map? Or is there anything changed from my previous version 3.0.8?

Thx

**Edit:**

Osmdroid 3.0.8 - I can pan map, go through the map, left, right, top, down. I have displayed POIs on the map. I can double to tap to zoom, pinchzoom to zoom-in or zoom-out. I click on POI, then I have all vailable details about POI displayed.

Osmdroid 4.3 - I can pan map, go through same as before. The only difference is, when I tap on POI item, map does nothing. Then, If I tap on the point again or I want to pan map doesn't matter. Both gestures are now the same and I see displayed POI details. When adding POIs to the map, I am using my custom class which extends OverlayItem. Why it needs double tab? Why is seems to me, that displayed OverlayItems are now "separated" from the map? Because first touch on them seems I have to "active them first", and with another touch (no matter what kind of touch is is) finish my work and display POI details.

I have done no change to the source code, only swapped the libraries. What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT2:**

I think I have found the change between osmdroid 3.0.8 and 4.3. In my App I am evaluating which POI was clicked by OnItemGestureListener and its method onItemSingleTap. In OnTouchEvent I am displaying POI details. In Osmdroid 3.0.8, while tap on POI, there was call hierarchy 1) onItemSingleTap 2)onTouchEvent. In osmdorid 4.3, their calls are switched, so 1)OnTouchEvent 2)OnItemSingleTap, so my first touch generates nothing.

Comment: Why don't you use bonus pack? It has marker.

Comment: I have custom overlays ready, which were working well up Osmdroid 3.0.8. Now in 4.3 their behavior has suddenly changed... My overlays display POI icons, so I see no need to link another library because of this simple functionality

Comment: "After I have moved over the map" what do you mean? Perhaps expand on how this problem can be recreated.

Comment: I have added edit to my question

Comment: Matbe you can put your `EDIT2` to the answer for the issue and also provide solution, then you can have your bonus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I have found the change between osmdroid 3.0.8 and 4.3. In my App I am evaluating which POI was clicked by OnItemGestureListener and its method onItemSingleTap. In OnTouchEvent I am displaying POI details. In Osmdroid 3.0.8, while tap on POI, there was call hierarchy 1) onItemSingleTap 2)onTouchEvent. In osmdorid 4.3, their calls are switched, so 1)OnTouchEvent 2)OnItemSingleTap, so my first touch generates nothing.

Solution to this is: in onTouchEvent I get IGeoLocation from place I touch my finger. Then I look up the database and find all POIs with coordinates around my touch with distance lower then threshold. This threshold (e.g. +-0,010 lat and +-0,10 lon) must be set for each zoom differently. E.g. when having zoom 16, threshold is 0,001 (when click on 1 POI only, I don't want to see selection of distant points), when having zoom 12, I set threshold on 0,125, so my finger selects only some POIs which are together and not the whole map. So If you have ability in your app to touch multiple POIs, be aware of this change in Osmdroid 4.3.